# Game logic with Dynamics

Tags: game-engine, modifiers, physics, collision

I'm new to the Blender Game Engine.

I have several floating static cube meshes. How do I make a cube fall once it collides with my character?

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the object physics to dinamic.

[image]

2. In logic editor add:

   always sensor > AND > Edit object **suspend Dinamics**

   **collision** sensor > AND > Edit object **Restore Dinamics**

[image]

**Note:** i used delay sensor to test but you need an collision sensor as in the next img.

3. With Python script:

   add an always and collision sensor to a python controller.

[image]

Text.py

```
from bge import logic

def main(controller):
    colsen = controller.sensors['Collision']
    if not 'init' in controller.owner.getPropertyNames():
        controller.owner.suspendDynamics()
        controller.owner['init'] = True        
    if colsen.positive:
        controller.owner.restoreDynamics()      

main(logic.getCurrentController())
```

**Related [Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=suspend#bge.types.KX_GameObject.suspendDynamics)**